# How to parse Daydream Controller BLE GATT output?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, daydream

I'm currently trying to get the Daydream controller to work with Hololens.
Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730809/use-daydream-controller-on-hololens-or-outside-daydream) as a guide I tried to read the information the controller gave back to me but I'm currently lost.

According to the linked answer, I should be able to get button presses if I go to line 19 and look at bytes 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8.
However, I seem to be getting 2 button presses just by having my finger over the track pad on the controller.
Also, I'm having an impossible time getting finger position on the track pad, and the rotation rotation values of the controller.

Here is an example of the byte array I get when the controller is flat on the table.

```
204,91,255,185,176,252,239,252,68,70,0,64,0,0,3,254,192,0,0,0
```

Here is the same byte array in bits.

```
0011001100000000
1101101000000000
1111111100000000
1001110100000000
0000110100000000
0011111100000000
1111011100000000
0011111100000000
0010001000000000
0110001000000000
0000000000000000
0000001000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
1100000000000000
0111111100000000
0000001100000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
```

If someone could help me parse what this means I would greatly appreciate it.

**Update 1:** 
The first 5 bits of row 19 is button inputs.

```
19-1 : track pad button
19-2 : the o button
19-3 : the - button
19-4 : volume down button
19-5 : volume up button
```

Answer (score -2):

I find some information about this. 
This is the link:

https://hackernoon.com/how-i-hacked-google-daydream-controller-c4619ef318e4

The only wrong is the Data from the buttons. Ignore it. You are right. 
Other thing, the first 14 bits are unknown. I tried to find some relation with data but I couldn't it.