# Daydream Controller Protocol

Tags: android, controller, bluetooth-lowenergy, daydream

I follow this thread from 
[Use Daydream Controller on HoloLens or outside Daydream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730809/use-daydream-controller-on-hololens-or-outside-daydream?answertab=votes#tab-top)

when we tried to lay controller in flat on table. BLE scanner get ByteArray

0x26200067FFFF70008421FF800000000000000001

and I followed the parser code, get xAcc = 8187, yAcc = 528, zAcc = 8182 looks like something wrong? Because I got Acc X=-156.74, Y = -10.1, Z=156.64

Please guide me what should I revise? Thank you.

Comment: Something seems off with your bit extraction for xAcc/zAcc... I got xAcc = 2, yAcc = 528, and zAcc = -8 on that byte array. As an example, xAcc would be in the bytes `0x700084` and the bits would be `01110*0000000000010*000100`, the section between the '*' is the extracted bits to use.

Comment: Thanks, I found I less thinking about "signed bit" , so I add value = (value << 19) >> 19, it is ok. Thanks your sharing again.