# Does Magnetometer be contained of Daydream Controller?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, controller, bluetooth-lowenergy, daydream

I followed these two thread.
A: https://hackernoon.com/how-i-hacked-google-daydream-controller-
   c4619ef318e4#.uaaf84o6p

and

B: [Use Daydream Controller on HoloLens or outside Daydream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730809/use-daydream-controller-on-) 
   hololens-or-outside-daydream

A says it has mag, B says it is fusion(orientation), I think it is fusion, because I check develop website

https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/reference/class/gvr-controller

It says, there are no properties about accessing magnetometer, and the Orientation

Quaternion
Returns the controller's current orientation in space, as a quaternion.

Looks like a Rotation Vector, because it is quaternion. This is my reason, If I wrong, please correct me. Thank you.

Comment: Just a note - Daydream orientation is not a quaternion but an axis-angle encoded orientation, which then can be turned into a quaternion in your application code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to orientation (which already fuses the sensors), you can access the [accelerometer](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/reference/class/gvr-controller#class_gvr_controller_1aa11668cb79b6827549520f5661939ab9)
and the [Gyro](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/reference/class/gvr-controller#class_gvr_controller_1a566a0277426fe480779e85922ff63bb7).  The magnetometer is not currently exposed in the API.  If you have a specific need in mind, I'd recommend asking on the Unity forums.

Comment: When looking just at the changing bits it looked like it was magnetometer data. When looking closely at all the gvr code that portion of bits goes to an orientation event class. I initially made the same mistake myself in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730809/use-daydream-controller-on-hololens-or-outside-daydream#answer-40753551). There is also a working example at [github](https://github.com/cwei/DaydreamController/tree/master/DaydreamController) for iOS.